# What is an estimator and how to construct it?

Tags: estimation, estimators

The definition of an estimator "rule that tells how to calculate an estimate " as given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Estimator.html#:%7E:text=An%20estimator%20is%20a%20rule,(1)) is not clear to me. If I make measurements of some quantity, say age in a group of N people, my outcomes will be $x_1, \dots, x_N$ where $x_i$ represents the age of $i$-th person. One can now talk about the mean as the quantity that gives us "rough idea" about the age of this group.

I want to understand how is the notion of *estimator* relevant to a situation like above (if at all it is)? What the estimator actually is and how to construct it?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47728/what-is-the-difference-between-an-estimator-and-a-statistic/61828#61828

Answer (score 0):

The **mean** age would be the estimator, and the mean **value** would be an estimate, a statistic from the example you mentioned.